# Running RandomForest in parallel on different nodes in a cluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, random-forest, parallel.foreach

I want to run randomForest in Parallel on a Cluster (university server) where I can reserve 4 nodes simultaneously, which further contains 12 cores each. I used the foreach and doSNOW package as mentioned in the foreach package description but by using the following code, I can see that all the load is on just first node while for other 3 nodes, there is no memory consumption. Can somebody guide me how I can edit this code so that every core of every node get equal work to do and then we combine it into 1 forest.

```
> library("foreach")
> library("doSNOW")
> registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(48, type="SOCK"))

> x <- matrix(runif(500), 100)
> y <- gl(2, 50)

> rf <- foreach(ntree = rep(22, 48), .combine = combine, .packages = "randomForest") %dopar%
+    randomForest(x, y, ntree = ntree)
> rf
Call:
randomForest(x = x, y = y, ntree = ntree)
Type of random forest: classification
Number of trees: 1056
```

Comment: Are you using a batch queueing system (such as Torque, LSF, or Slurm) to request the four nodes?

Comment: Great answer below but I wanted to add that you should talk to your university cluster admin(s). They will be able to help you in the best way for your specific cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start the workers on multiple nodes in a SOCK cluster, the first argument to `makeCluster` should be a vector of node names rather than a number. In that case, `makeCluster` will launch a worker on each of the specified nodes using the `ssh` command.

For example, to start 12 workers on each of the nodes "n1", "n2", "n3", and "n4", you could use:

```
> nodelist <- rep(c("n1", "n2", "n3", "n4"), each=12)
> cl <- makeCluster(nodelist, type="SOCK")
> registerDoSNOW(cl)
```

Note that each node name appears in `nodelist` 12 times, so the length of `nodelist` is 48.

If you're using a batch queueing system to run your job, you should get the list of node names that were allocated to your job rather than hardcoding them in your script. You can usually get that information from an environment variable, but it depends on your batch queueing system. For example, with Torque you can get the node list using:

```
> nodelist <- readLines(Sys.getenv("PBS_NODEFILE"))
```

---

I prefer to create an MPI cluster using `makeMPIcluster` and register it with doSNOW when running parallel jobs on HPC clusters, but this approach can be more difficult for beginners. For example, you must have the Rmpi package installed and you must execute your R script via the "mpirun" command. If you can get help from a knowledgable sysadmin, it will probably work better in the long run.

Yet another approach is to use the doMPI parallel backend instead of doSNOW, since doMPI was specifically designed for use on HPC clusters. For more information, see the [doMPI vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMPI/vignettes/doMPI.pdf).

---

Also note that you'll get better performance if you use the foreach `.multicombine=TRUE` argument in this example. That will cause the `combine` function to be called once rather than 47 times.

Comment: Many thanks for a detailed reply. The HPC I am working on uses OAR Batch Scheduler. Can you tell me how can I get list of nodes in OAR? Secondly, what you're suggesting is to use Rmpi instead of doSNOW? If I use Rmpi package then the code for runing randomForest will be the same or I have to modify it as per Rmpi package?

Comment: @Newbie I wasn't suggesting that you use pure Rmpi. I was suggesting that you could use doSNOW with an MPI cluster (created using the `makeMPIcluster` function), or you could use doMPI instead of doSNOW. Both options require Rmpi, but you don't use it directly.

Comment: @Newbie Try using the OAR_NODEFILE environment variable. The documentation suggests it works just like PBS_NODEFILE, in which case you can use essentially the same code as the Torque example listed in my answer.

Comment: I am doing this but at point of making the cluster I get following error:  `Bad owner or permissions on /home/users/tony/.ssh/config`

Comment: @Newbie snow uses ssh to start the remote workers, and file permissions is a big issue when using ssh. You may have to remove any "group" and "other" permissions on "config" using a command such as "chmod go-rwx /home/users/tony/.ssh/config".